# curl 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate [url] https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

Reciente Rackspace ha actualizado sus certificados SSL para algunos servicios servicios, uno de ellos es el de OpenCloud que almacena archivos. Algunos desarrolladores que hemos estado usando el módulo `php-opencloud` hemos estado experimentando errores como este:

> [curl] 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate [url] https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens

O este otro:

> ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

¿Qué se hacer para mitigar este error?

Answer (score 1):

El api de rackspace hace uso de la librería Guzzle que verica el SSL de su sitio, al no haber un certificado o uno desactualizado lanza el error descrito. Hay varias alternativas para dar solventarlo, cada solución le sirve a unos o a otros.

#### Opción 1: php.ini - curl.cainfo

1. Descargar el archivo [cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)
2. Ponerlo en alguna ubicación tal como C:\Apache\php\
3. Editar el archivo `php.ini`, agregar la siguiente línea:

   ```
   curl.cainfo="C:\Apache24\php\ca-bundle.crt"
   ```
4. Reiniciar apache y listo

#### Opción 2: Reemplazar certificado de Guzzle

Cuando se instala guzzle por composer también se instala el certificado en la siguiente ubicación:

> vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Resources\cacert.pem

Descargar el certificado [cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) y sustituirlo por el de guzzle

#### Opción 3: Deshabilitar la verificación SSL (no recomendada)

Aunque es una opción, no es recomendada por las vulnerabilidades de seguridad:

```
$client->setDefaultOption('verify', false);
```